# Returning unique results in a joined select

Tags: sql, t-sql, unique, distinct

I need help with a query that check the MSDB-database for SQL Server Agent Job results. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), Serverproperty('ServerName')),
       a.run_status,
       b.run_requested_date,
       c.name,
       CASE c.enabled
         WHEN 1 THEN 'Enabled'
         ELSE 'Disabled'
       END,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, Rtrim(19000101))+(a.run_duration *
       9 +
       a.run_duration % 10000 * 6 + a.run_duration % 100 * 10) / 216e4, 108),
       b.next_scheduled_run_date
FROM   (msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory a
        LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity b
          ON b.job_history_id = a.instance_id)
       JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobs c
         ON b.job_id = c.job_id
ORDER  BY c.name
```

So far so good, but running it returns several results for the same jobs depending on how many times they have ran up until the query. This is no good. I want only one result per job, and only the latest.

If I add the the string:
WHERE b.session_id=(SELECT MAX(session_id)  from msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity) 
It works better, but then it only lists the latest jobs depending on the session_id parameter. This will exclude jobs that haven't run for a while and is not good either.

Can someone help me with this?
I have tried with DISTINCT and/or GROUP BY but can't get it to work.

Comment: Which SQL Server version? (this decides whether `ROW_NUMBER()` is available)

Answer (score 1):

```
with cte
     AS (SELECT
     Convert(varchar(30), SERVERPROPERTY('ServerName')) AS ServerName,
     a.run_status,
     b.run_requested_date,
     c.name,
     CASE c.enabled
       WHEN 1 THEN 'Enabled'
       Else 'Disabled'
     END
        AS Enabled,
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CONVERT(DATETIME, RTRIM(19000101))+(a.run_duration
        * 9 +
     a.run_duration % 10000 * 6 + a.run_duration % 100 * 10) / 216e4, 108)
        AS run_duration,
     b.next_scheduled_run_date,
     ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by b.job_id ORDER BY b.run_requested_date
        DESC) AS RN
         FROM   (msdb.dbo.sysjobhistory a
                 LEFT JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobactivity b
                   ON b.job_history_id = a.instance_id)
                join msdb.dbo.sysjobs c
                  on b.job_id = c.job_id)
SELECT *
FROM   cte
WHERE  RN = 1
ORDER  BY name
```

Comment: Thanks, this works well, but when I add a CASE clause for the run_status column I'll recieve an error like "No column name was specified for column 2 of 'cte'."

Comment: @Alex - You need to make sure all of your calculated columns are given explicit aliases as I did for `ServerName` etc.

Comment: Hey! That works like a charm after giving it an alias. Thanks very much. Appreciated!

Comment: Actually, that did not work completly. It has problems listing the next run date/time of the jobs. Seems to be severeral posts about the same jobs in some of the columns. This makes the joins faulty since thejob_id with the highest session_id might not always contain the information about the next run date. Fairly odd though!